# Why doesn't the removeChild remove the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written this scrip to take out ads on a website. Was working on it the whole day.

This is the JS code:

```
var timer = setInterval(deletor, 1);

function deletor() {
    timer;
    var slider = document.querySelector("#slider-con");
    var bannerTop = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(2)")
    var bannerMiddle = document.querySelector("#MainContent > iframe");
    var bannerRandom = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(7)");
    var bannerRandom2 = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(6)");


        if (slider == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            slider.parentNode.removeChild(slider);
        };

        if (bannerTop == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            bannerTop.parentNode.removeChild(bannerTop);
        };

        if (bannerMiddle == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            bannerMiddle.parentNode.removeChild(bannerMiddle);
        };

        if (bannerRandom == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            bannerRandom.parentNode.removeChild(bannerRandom);
        };

        if (bannerRandom2 == undefined) {
            return false;
        } else {
            bannerRandom2.parentNode.removeChild(bannerRandom2);
        };

};
```

Now, as you can see, it gets the values first and then goes through if statements. Idea behind this is: On first try, it deletes the elements and on the second one, it stops the function.
But when I inserted this last element, it won't delete it. The ID is correct, everything is correct but it won't delete the element, so I keep getting the same alert over and over.

Also, I found out that, I get this banner ad on two places. When I have "var bannerRandom = document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(7)");" this, it appears as "document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(6)")" this, and when I have both, it appears as "document.querySelector("#MainContent > div:nth-child(6)")" this. And it's not deleted.

Console shows no errors.

Comment: *"On first try, it deletes the elements and on the second one, it stops the function."* That doesn't make any sense. What are these "tries" you speak of?

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are completely different programming languages. Another user and I have collaborated to remove the irrelevant [tag:java] tag and add the relevant [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Might have might have instantly selected Java when typing Java (meant Javascript)>

T.J. I'm referring to if statements and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Your various statements in the form:

```
if (slider == undefined) {
    return false;
} else {
    slider.parentNode.removeChild(slider);
};
```

mean this: "If `slider` wasn't found in the DOM, **exit the function**. Otherwise, remove the slider and continue the function."

So that means your function will terminate the first time one of the elements you're looking for doesn't exist. Since it terminates then, none of the other elements after it is checked. That seems unlikely to be what you want to do.

You probably just wanted:

```
if (slider) {
    slider.parentNode.removeChild(slider);
}
```

...and so on.

---

Note that you don't put `;` at the end of a block attached to a flow-control statement like `if` or `else`, which is why I've removed it above. (Doing so is harmless, because JavaScript ignores them; but it's pointless.)